# JavaScript, array as a parameter

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

How you can make this more efficient, imagine a method that you don't know how much parameters you'll need.

For example a simple ajax insert, but you don't know how much inputs has the html...
so then you need to send for example 4 will be like this one:

```
function insert_these(data1, data2, data3, data4){
     $.post( 'test.php', { dat1: data1, dat2: data2, dat3: data3, dat4: data4 );
};
```

But, if you want more than 4 inputs?

How you can make a function with a parameters as a array, something like this:

```
inputs = new array();

function insert_these(inputs){

    //then the rest of code

    $.post(   'test.php',   for (var i = 0; i < inputs.lenght; i++){
    dat+i: inputs+i,   }; );

};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called a [variadic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function) and it's easy to build in JavaScript : There's an [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) pseudo-array already available in your function.

Simply iterate over it just as you do over an array and build your object :

```
function insert_these(){
    var obj = {};
    for (var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++) obj['dat'+(i+1)] = arguments[i];
    $.post('test.php', obj);
}
```

Comment: Notice that the function argument list `data1, data2, data3, data4` is unused and not needed. You can change the function definition to `function insert_these() { ... }`.

Comment: @MattiasBuelens You're right, that was just a unfixed copy-paste

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use an object like:

```
var params = {
  data1: 'data1',
  data2: 'data2'
}

insert(params);

function insert(parameters) {
   // other stuff here
   $.post('test.php', parameters);
   // other stuff here
}
```